# How to Concatenate variable name in a vba loop?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to compare items in 2 arrays. If an item is present in the first array but not the second array, then I want to display its value. But I am struggling with the way to do this - my current attempt is below:

```
Dim l1     As Long
Dim l2     As Long
Dim Size1  As Long
Dim Size2  As Long

' array1= listbox1 contents
'array2 =listbox2 contents

Size1 = UBound(array1)
Size2 = UBound(array2)
Dim bln As Boolean

For l1 = 1 To Size1
   bln = False
   For l2 = 1 To Size2
       If array1(l1) = array2(l2) Then
          bln = True
       End If
   Next l2
   If bln = False Then
   Me.Label_nonmatchitems.Caption = "Do not have a match for item(s) " & l1    

  Next l1

End sub
```

If the 3 items in array1 does not match in array2, then my label is displaying 3 times, like this:

```
 Do not have a match for item(s) value1
 Do not have a match for item(s) value8
 Do not have a match for item(s) value10
```

Instead I was looking for an output like this:

```
      Do not have a match for item(s) value1,value8,value10
```

There is something wrong with the logic in my loop - can you help me find and fix the error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I have edited the question - I think it is now sufficiently clear that it does not need to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code as follows:

```
Dim l1     As Long
Dim l2     As Long
Dim Size1  As Long
Dim Size2  As Long

Size1 = UBound(array1)
Size2 = UBound(array2)
Dim bln As Boolean
Dim nonMatching As String

nonMatching = ""

For l1 = 1 To Size1
   bln = False
   For l2 = 1 To Size2
       If array1(l1) = array2(l2) Then
          bln = True
       End If
   Next l2
   If bln = False Then
     nonMatching = nonMatching & l1 & ", "
   End If
  Next l1
  If Len(nonMatching) > 0 Then
    nonMatching = Left(nonMatching, Len(nonMatching) - 2) ' strip final comma-space    
    Me.Label_nonmatchitems.Caption = "Do not have a match for item(s) " & nonMatching   
  Else
    Me.Label_nonmatchitems.Caption = "All items match"
  End If

End Sub
```

You build the string of nonmatching items in the loop, then print the entire result at the end.

Comment: *nonMatching = Left(nonMatching, Len(nonMatching) - 1)*  Cannot strip the comma.

Comment: I wonder if that's because I actually add `comma, space` - so you have to remove 2 characters. Also, I suppose that if there were no non-matching values, then there is nothing to strip. So you might want to test for the length: `If Len(nonMatching) > 0 Then nonMatching = Left(nonMatching, Len(nonMatching) - 1)`. Updating answer now...

Answer (score 0):

```
"Do not have a match for item(s) "
```

Move this part above the for loop.

```
Text="Do not have a match for item(s) "
For l1 = 1 To Size1
    bln = False
    ...
    Text2 = Text2 & L1
Next l1

Me.Label_nonmatchitems.Caption = Text & Text2
```